# Wishlist Error with Price

Tags: price, wishlist, magento-1.4

I am having an issue with the wishlist. My store sells downloadable PDF knitting patterns. When a customer adds an item to their wishlist the price of the item is shown as 0.00 even though the item added has a price. When the item is then added to the cart the price is then correct in the cart.

Is there somewhere i can look to change a setting that allows the price to be shown correctly in the wishlist or alternatively take out the price all together on the wishlist. I am not very experienced with Magento so any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

I have attached 2 images. The first one shows the wishlist showing the wrong price of R0.00 while the second shows the cart after clicking the add to cart button showing the correct price of R20.00.

[image: This one shows how the item is showing a zero Price (R0.00)]

[image: Cart Is correctly priced]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is a little late but maybe this could help you.

You have this code in your view.phtml

> < ? php
>         $product = $item->getProduct();  ?>

So with this code you can get the price:

< ? php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product) ?>